# Как вычислить максимальное значение x, в котором функция получает максимальное значение (лямбда-функция python)

Tags: python, lambda, max

Как рассчитать x, в котором функция получает максимальное значение, используя python функцию lambda.
Например, l = [1, 5, 4, -1], функция x ^ 2. 5 - это x, в котором функция получает максимальное значение.

Comment: Welcome to russian stackoverflow. Please, translate you question to russian language

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
In [315]: l = [1, 5, 4, -1]

In [316]: def func(x):
     ...:     return x**2
     ...:

In [317]: max(l, key=func)
Out[317]: 5
```

или:

```
In [321]: max(l, key=lambda x: x**2)
Out[321]: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
from functools import reduce

X = [1, 5, 4, -1]
max_x = reduce(lambda a, b: a if a**2 > b**2 else b, X)
```

Ну а вообще для такой функции как `x^2` очевидно, что максимальное значение будет у максимального `X`, а для этого достаточно просто на списке с вашими значениями использовать `max()`